# Spring boot project not load resources

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot, freemarker

I have spring boot project with this structure

```
srs-
 -main
   -java
      -MvcConfigurer.java
      -LkApplication.java
   -resource
      -static
         -css
      -templates
         -layout
           -defoultLayout.ftl
           -header.ftl
           -footer.ftl
        -index.ftl
```

in `defoultLayout.ftl` I include CSS file

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../static/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='../../static/css/core.css'>
</head>
```

But it  not loaded. I have some project with like structure and them all loaded but this not.

My classes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LkApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
        resolver.setCache(true);
        resolver.setPrefix("");
        resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
        resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() throws IOException, TemplateException {
        FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory factory = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory();
        factory.setTemplateLoaderPaths("classpath:templates", "src/main/resource/templates");
        factory.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
        result.setConfiguration(factory.createConfiguration());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

How can I load resources files to my springboot project?
I use: `springboot,freemarker,bootstrap`

Comment: Did you ever find out what caused this problem? I have a similar issue with my springboot app

Answer (score 1):

If it's maven or gradle, the standard folder structure should be `src/main/resources`.  The build will then place them in your (assuming) executable spring boot jar.

Providing you don't have security blocking any endpoints you should be able to reference the files as follows;

`<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/core.css'>`

note 'static' is stripped from the path.

Comment: strange but when I added this line to make things work. but now again nothing downloads

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot by default looks for resources at `resources` directory. I had the same problem in my prject.

change the directory name `resource` to `resources` // note **s** at the end

after this change, refresh project, it will work

Comment: where I need change name of resource? folder?

Comment: change the directory name resource to resources

Comment: it's called "resources"

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, was:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The default location in SpringBoot is:

- /META-INF/resources/
- /resources/
- /static/
- /public/

Which means the starting point is already in the right directory and you need to go from there, i.e.:

> bootstrap-3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

No slashes or anything upfront!